# Working example of og:audio:artist and og:audio:album

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

Can someone identify ONE WEB PAGE where `<meta property="og:audio:artist">` and `<meta property="og:audio:album">` are actually working to set the Artist and Album when sharing the URL of the page?

I have been banging away at http://www.coises.com/songs/sfcarol.htm for hours, trying every permutation of order of META tags, XML tag formats (even though it’s an HTML page), etc. (Note: though I have a home-grown share button on the page, I’m talking about sharing the URL of the page in the status box on Facebook itself as the test case.)

All I can get is that all words in the title are capitalized, even though it isn’t specified that way, and the Artist and Album are always Unknown. (For another song/page, "8/9/95", even the title won’t show.) The description also doesn’t show when doing the share, though it does show in the posted story.

I tried searching, and I tried places like ReverbNation and SoundCloud, but nobody seems to use the `og:audio` tags. (For videos, copying the way YouTube does it appears to work perfectly, http://www.coises.com/songs/risingup.htm being an example.) If I could see just one working example, I suspect I could figure it out.

Comment: I think those tags are still in beta.

Comment: They’re shown in the last example at the bottom of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ which states that it describes the current production version. Perhaps this simply _doesn’t work_ — if it’s a known bug that’s been reported, and I just didn’t know the right way to find it, that would be an (unhappy) answer, too. As it stands, the documentation says **og:audio:artist**, etc. should work; but if they do, there’s some bit of magic I haven’t stumbled upon, which is why I’d like to see just one working example (or confirmation that the documentation is known to be wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own song pages (e.g., http://www.coises.com/songs/floodplain.htm and most other song pages on my site) are now working examples.

It turns out the problem was simple: **og:audio:artist** and **og:audio:album** do not work unless **og:audio:title** is also supplied. I had assumed that would default to **og:title**; it seems it must be explicitly specified.

The linter still says the **og:audio:{title|artist|album}** tags are not allowed, but they work.

Comment: Those tags might work now that they've rolled out the new OpenGraph stuff in the last few days, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Those OG tags still seem to be in beta.  below I've included the linter results for five different websites that facebook is in partnership with.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmog.com%2Fm%2Ftrack%2F57587005

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deezer.com%2Fmusic%2Ftrack%2F6461440

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rhapsody.com%2Fartist%2Ftrombone-shorty%2Falbum%2Ffor-true

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vevo.com%2Fwatch%2Fj-cole-featuring-trey-songz-j-cole-1%2Fcant-get-enough%2FUSQX91101318

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Ftrack%2F3ssX20QT5c3nA9wk78V1LQ

Comment: Well, the tags I’m trying to use are described at [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/] which states that it describes the current production version.

Comment: Notice that linting my page http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coises.com%2Fsongs%2Fsfcarol.htm shows, at the bottom, that **Type of Share** is **Music**: this creates an in-line audio player, which is exactly what I want. The Vevo example above yields **Video**, and all the others use some apparently much more complicated technique, with **og:audio:type** set to **audio/vnd.facebook.bridge**. I’ll search on that, but I suspect it’s getting into something far more involved than the simple thing I want to do: set the Title/Artist/Album correctly.

Comment: Yep, the **audio/vnd.facebook.bridge** is a whole, much more complicated thing... I really, really don’t want to swat a fly with a sledgehammer here. Thank you for the examples... but they don’t show what I need. If I could see an example of the tags described in the very last example box the bottom of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ actually working...

Comment: I gave you five working examples when you asked for one.  Can you accept my answer please since your question was merely to get a working example? Also be aware that this functionality is BETA and may be riddled with bugs.  If you find a bug, please report it to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/Facebook